# How to install ARC without installing any ARC app

Tags: google-chrome-arc

Is there a way to install ARC extension in Chrome without installing any ARC app? We need to test our app on multiple machines (Desktop), but since there is no ARC app available in Chrome store which supports desktop versions of Chrome (other than Chromebook) which will download ARC while installing the app.
We are able to sideload ARC app as a zip file in chrome://extensions page. Do we need to install ARC welder app on each machine in order to install ARC?

Comment: Just FYI, if you're testing your ARC App for release, you're better off testing on ChromeOS rather than testing on Desktop Chrome.  There are subtle platform differences, so you may end up chasing bugs that don't exist on ChromeOS or depending on functionality that won't work on ChromeOS by testing on Desktop Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing ARC Welder is the only supported way to get the ARC runtime on Desktop Chrome right now.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/arc-welder/emfinbmielocnlhgmfkkmkngdoccbadn